# Writing to multiple cells in excel, using python, but get error message: tuple has no attribute value

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am pulling three names from sheet_obj but when I try to write these three names to another excel file, I get an error stating that the following tuple object has no attribute value: sheet['A1:A3'] = cell_obj.value

If I change it to sheet['A1'] = cell_obj.value, then I only get data in one cell instead of three in separate cells. Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
import openpyxl
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(latest_file)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
max_column = sheet_obj.max_column
for i in range(1, max_column+1):
    cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=1, column = i)
    print(cell_obj.value)



import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active
sheet.title = 'Sheet 1'
my_list = cell_obj.value

sheet['A1:A3'] = cell_obj.value
wb.save('hello_world.xlsx')
```

Comment: What is the full error output?

Comment: @C_Z_ this is what i get. self[key].value = value
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the entire traceback of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cell_obj is referring to only one cell value and not to all 3 cells. You can set values by setting each cell.

```py
    import openpyxl
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(latest_file)
    sheet_obj = wb_obj.active
    max_column = sheet_obj.max_column
    
    #for i in range(1, max_column+1):
    #   cell_obj = sheet_obj.cell(row=1, column = i)
    #   print(cell_obj.value)
    
    # Save cell values into a list
    my_list = [sheet_obj.cell(row=1, column = i).value for i in range(1, max_column+1)]
    print(my_list)
    
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    sheet = wb.active
    sheet.title = 'Sheet 1'
    # my_list = cell_obj.value

    # Iterate over list and update each cell
    for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
        sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=1).value = v
    
    wb.save('hello_world.xlsx')
```

Comment: @kendfss what do you mean i just need to set?

Comment: @michaelvdnest thanks for this. this worked but the data is posted in the column instead of a row. How can i make the data transfer to row instead of column?